# Exceptions and Control Flow

Tags: javascript, exception

I am curious if this kind of usage with try/catch blocks is bad practice (control flow). 
Here, I am checking if an input from an array of usernames have any non-alphanumeric characters. I am simulating a group of people submitting (username, name, and age), and therefore the results can be "unpredictable".

Would this be considered using exceptions for control flow? Should I completely get rid of them?

```
function checkDuplicate(name, array){
    for (let user of array){
        if (name == user.username)
            return true;
    } 
}

function checkFormat(testExp,phrase){
    if (testExp.test(phrase) == true)
        return false;
    return true
}

function errorCheck (newUsers){
    let accepted = [];
    let rejected = [];

    for (let user of newUsers){
        let status = true;

        try{ //check existing username
            if (checkDuplicate(user.username,accepted) == true){
                status = false;
                throw new Error (`ERROR: Username (${user.username}) already exists`)
            }
            }catch(error){
                console.log(error.message);
            }

        let regexp = new RegExp("\\W+");

        //checkusername format
        try{
            if (!checkFormat(regexp, user.username))
                throw new Error (`ERROR: Username (${user.username}) the username cannot contain spaces or special characters`)
        }catch(error){ 
            console.log(error.message);
        }
        //check first/last name
        try{

            if (!checkFormat(regexp,user.first) || !checkFormat(regexp,user.last))
                throw new Error (`ERROR: Username (${user.username}) first/last name cannot contain spaces or special characters`)
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error.message);
        }
        //check age > 21
        try{
        if (user.age < 21){
            status = false;
            throw new Error (`ERROR: Username (${user.username}) must be 21 years old`);
        }
    }catch(error){
            console.log(error.message);
    }

        if (status == true) accepted.push(user);
        else rejected.push(user);

    }

    return [accepted, rejected];
```

Comment: What is your try/catch even for? Why don't you just log the message without throwing?

Comment: @ASDFGerte I suppose my level of programming experience and exposure is not enough to see where the practical uses are. I will look into this further! For now, I know that I do not require the exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a *lot* of syntax noise which doesn't accomplish anything that plain `if`/`else` statements can't. Unnecessarily verbose code results in more surface area for bugs, which should be avoided when possible. Exceptions should generally be *exceptional*, for cases when ordinary checks in the current function won't suffice.

You're already using `if`/`else` - instead of throwing and then catching *in addition*, simply put the logic you need inside the `if`/`else`.

You can also use `.some` to check to see if a user with the same username already exists in the array.

```
function errorCheck(newUsers) {
  const accepted = [];
  const rejected = [];
  for (const user of newUsers) {
    let status = true;
    if (accepted.some(({ username }) => user.username === username)) {
      status = false;
      console.log(`ERROR: Username (${user.username}) already exists`)
    }
    if (/\W/.test(user.username)) {
      status = false;
      console.log(`ERROR: Username (${user.username}) the username cannot contain spaces or special characters`)
    }
    if (/\W/.test(user.first) || /\W/.test(user.last)) {
      status = false;
      console.log(`ERROR: Username (${user.username}) first/last name cannot contain spaces or special characters`)
    }
    if (user.age < 21) {
      status = false;
      console.log(`ERROR: Username (${user.username}) must be 21 years old`);
    }
    (status ? accepted : rejected).push(user);
  }
  return [accepted, rejected];
}
```

Exceptions *can* be useful for control flow, but only when *ordinary* tools for control flow won't be good enough.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I was looking around for a clear explanation. Having you explain it with reference to my own example really helped.

Comment: quick question! Why did you utilize the curly braces while specifying the parameter of the arrow function within .some? ({username}) => ....

Comment: That's required for the syntax to be valid - if you omit it, it won't work